# How can I optimize mongos when it is using a lot of CPU cycles?

Tags: mongodb

I have a pretty standard mongo setup with `mongos` running on the app servers, three `mongoc` instances running and two shards of three `mongod` instances each.

It all runs fine, but all of the documentation I see says that `mongos` should be a fairly lightweight process. That doesn't seem to be the case with me. I'm running a test that simulates several users making requests and the limiting factor seems to be the `mongos` process. nginx and php-fpm are running on the app servers as well, but they are only using about 15% of the CPU during the test. `mongos` is at around 85%.

I can add more app servers to compensate, but since `mongos` is supposed to be more lightweight, I thought maybe I'm doing something wrong. As far as I can tell, all of my queries are indexed. I'm using the default MongoIDs in each collection as the sharding index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `mongos` is having to do large in-memory sorts or lots of merge-sorts, map-reduce, counts etc. then it will not be lightweight.  When all it has to do is determine what shards you are sending queries to, then it will be lightweight.

When it has to do a lot of aggregation of data from those shards, merge them, sort them and then hand them back to the end user, then it's going to be working a lot harder.

If you want to see what's going on with the `mongos` then log into it and run [`db.currentOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) to see what is running at that point - since it is a single point in time, you may need several samples for the culprits to be obvious.  Similarly, [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongostat/) can give you a view of operations running over time that may help.

Finally - as a possible strategy to find out what users are the problem ones, you could have each person temporarily connected to a separate `mongos` and see how they perform then - it may take some refactoring to do so, but it could be a useful option.